# Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{2^n}$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am asked the following question:

> Determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2^n}$ is convergent or divergent

My approach was to find

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2^n} = 0
$$. since the sine function oscilates between 0 and 1 and the exponential function just keeps growing. But that alone won't guarantee convergency. Which approach should I tackle now?

I thought about the integral test, but the integration process won't be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $\sum\frac1{2^n}$ convergent?

Comment: $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2^n}=\sin^2 x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(x)^2\leq 1$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)^2}{2^n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1$$
I assume you meant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)^2}{2^n}$ but the conclusion is still valid.

Comment: I actually mean $\sin^2 x$ but I get the point, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Cm7F7Bb has just noted, for any real $x$
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{2^n} 
= \sin^2x \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}
= \sin^2 x.
$$